# Did Bhishma give pain to an insect in his 101th previous birth because of which he got bed of arrows?

Tags: mahabharata, karma, bhishma

I saw [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiHZOcrea9g) in which it is shown that Bhisma got bed of arrows because he gave the pain to an insect and threw it on cactus due to which Bhishma got bed of arrows.

Is this story correct?

Comment: does that video give pramaan (source) for their claims ?

Comment: @mar I have given the link to the video.  Also I searched on google about it and found this story is written at multiple places including in a published book on google-books. I just couldn't find the verse number of it.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/amrithavahini/c/-a09XepaQt8?pli=1

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this forum is not to verify the voracity of youtube or other internet social media postings. Questions on the source of a youtube posting should be addressed to the youtube author.

Comment: Bishma is 8th vasu devatha who instigated other seven brothers to rob sage vasista of his cow kamedhu on pre text of his wife.. due to his sapa he had to suffer. but according to legend arjuna prepared bed arrows for safe sleeeping..because if you see physics one stand on bed of nails, so there is no piercing happened This mean Arjuna konw physics.